# Py_InitModule and PyString_InternFromString in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, native-code

I want to update my Python version from 2.7 to 3.5.

When compiling code that uses `PyString_InternFromString` and this `Py_InitModule`

I get error messages:

```
Error   199 error C3861: 'Py_InitModule': identifier not found
Error   196 error C3861: 'PyString_InternFromString': identifier not found
```

My question is,  What is the equivalent to those identifiers in python 3.5?

Comment: for `py_InitModule` [python 3 uses a different structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305731/compiler-cant-find-py-initmodule-is-it-deprecated-and-if-so-what-should-i) and for `PyString_InternFromString`, it is just [unavailable for python 3](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html#c.PyString_InternFromString)

Comment: @RNar: [Interning is still there, it's just that the C level type of the Python `str` changed.](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_InternFromString)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Py_InitModule`, you're now using [`PyModule_Create`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModule_Create). You can see [example usage in the tutorial example on the Python docs page](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example).

For interning, Py3's `str` is based on the Py2 `unicode` type; at the C-layer, you're using `PyUnicode` methods, e.g. [PyUnicode_InternFromString](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_InternFromString). You're still interning Python level `str`s, but the implementation type has changed.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28306354/320546 will help you with `Py_InitModule`
and `PyStr_InternFromString` is the Python 3 equivalent of `PyString_InternFromString`  (see http://py3c.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#c.PyStr_InternFromString)

Comment: `PyStr_InternFromString` is from a third party compatibility library, it's not the "Python 3 equivalent" of anything, it's a wrapper that calls the Py2 or Py3 version of the function, as appropriate.