# Why does it give me and ImportError when I am importing getch and have already installed it?

Tags: python, importerror, getch

I'm trying to import getch with python:

```
from getch import getch
```

But it gives me an error like:

```
ImportError: /opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/getch.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule
```

Any idea how to solve this?

(I have installed getch already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305731) and the fact that getch was last updated in 2013 implying it is python 2 just like the issue.  Try using python 2 or consider another package that doesn't have old c-bindings in it.