# Return a normal Python string from cffi function?

Tags: python, c, python-cffi

[This](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#main-mode-of-usage) explanation of cffi gives an example of how to declare a C function returning a float. You can also declare it to return a `char*`. I have adapted this toy example:

```
# my_ffi.py
...

ffibuilder.cdef("""
    char * my_cfun(void);
""")

...
```

If I do this, then I need the following Python at the call site to get it back into a Python string:

```
# user.py
from _my_ffi import ffi, lib

print(ffi.string(lib.my_cfun()))
```

How can I declare it such that the calling Python code sees an ordinary Python string, thus not needing the conversion? I have tried using PyObject * as the return type, but this causes cdef to fail to parse it:

```
cffi.CDefError: cannot parse "PyObject * my_cfun(void);"
```

The Googleability of this application is quite bad... I suspect there is a totally different way to pass python objects back and forth, but I have also definitely seen function signatures in C that contain PyObject.

Comment: See [ask]. Do a preliminary research. See [Conversions](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref.html#conversions). CFFI does not have the feature that you want. Anyway, why not create a wrapper which does the conversion? Or you can create a [Python C extension](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) if you work with your own C module.

Comment: If you're *returning* `char*` via Python CFFI, I'd bet dollars to donuts there's a memory leak lurking somewhere. Where does the memory come from? If it's not returning the address of a constant string, then who's responsible for allocating it? Who's responsible for *de*-allocating it?

Answer (score 1):

Like relent95 said, the answer is to write this Python function:

```
def stuff():
    return ffi.string(lib.my_cfunc())
```

Comment: Note: for Python 3 and newer, don't forget to convert the octet-string into a "real" string, with something like `ffi.string(lib.my_cfunc()).decode('ascii')`

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be a feature of cffi. I was able to get exactly what I was imagining with C Extensions, example in this answer: [Compiler can't find Py_InitModule() .. is it deprecated and if so what should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305731/compiler-cant-find-py-initmodule-is-it-deprecated-and-if-so-what-should-i)

This is much more similar to the Lua C API, but appears to be unrelated to cffi. I also found ctypes, which I have not yet tried.